# PAUSE instruction - unrecognized opcode `pause' in RISC-V

Tags: c, linux, assembly, riscv

I am currently working on riscv64 linux based on [SiFive Freedom Unleashed SDK](https://github.com/sifive/freedom-u-sdk).

I would like to implement pause instruction through extended asm instruction embedded in my C code. Below is an example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(){
        int a = 10;  
        __asm__ volatile("rep;nop;"::);
        return 0;
}
```

When I tried to compile the program, the assembler generates an error saying that: "Error: unrecognized opcode `rep'".

I tried to substitute it with `__asm__ __volatile__ ("pause"::);`, and similar error occurs: "Error: unrecognized opcode `pause'".

According to the The RISC-V Instruction Set Manual:

> PAUSE is encoded as a FENCE instruction with pred=W, succ=0, fm=0, rd=x0, and rs1=x0

Therefore, I assume the correct way to implement starts with `__asm__ volatile("fence")`, but how to implement the constraints (pred=W, succ=0, fm=0, rd=x0, and rs1=x0)?

If my understanding is incorrect, could anyone please tell me how to implement the pause instruction with extended asm?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `rep;nop` is how the x86 `pause` instruction (https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/pause) can be encoded with old x86 assemblers that don't recognize the `pause` mnemonic.  Those are x86 mnemonics, not RISC-V.  Of course a RISC-V assembler doesn't recognize the `rep` mnemonic (https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/rep:repe:repz:repne:repnz).  I'd suggest taking out that distraction from your question.

Comment: IDK why your RISC-V assembler wouldn't recognize the RISC-V `pause` mnemonic, unless it's new or some `-march` option is needed.  (clang trunk's built-in assembler doesn't handle it: https://godbolt.org/z/o6rxK7GE5).  You could encode it manually with `.word 0x...`.

Comment: @PeterCordes: Thanks for your reply. As for encoding it manually, did you mean __asm__ volatile(".word 0x...")?

Comment: Yes, but of course you need to check the RISC-V manual to figure out which 32-bit hex value to use, from the details for which fields go where for `fence`.

Comment: @PeterCordes: Thanks! I have found it here(http://staff.ustc.edu.cn/~comparch/reference/riscv-spec%EF%BC%880305%EF%BC%89.pdf) in section 2.7 on page 26.

Comment: @PeterCordes: Sorry but I am still confused about how to encode the value of x0, and what exactly W is in this case. Could you please give me some hint? Thanks in advance.

Comment: No idea, sorry.  I don't know RISC-V as well as I know x86, so all I can tell you for certain is that x86 `rep; nop` is totally irrelevant, just like the x86 `add` instruction has no relevance to RISC-V machine code for the RISC-V `add` instruction.

Comment: @PeterCordes: I appreciate your help throughout the discussion. I have tried __asm__ volatile("fence" ::: "memory"); and there's no compilation error, at least. I will try to figure out how to set the corresponding values and update here.

Comment: @PeterCordes re: encoding it manually: nice to know that the equivalent of setting a bunch of switches and a "load" button is still available in this modern era. I'd feared that'd vanished back in the 1970s!